# For $z \in \mathbb{C}$, |z-1| = 1 proof that arg(z-1) = 2arg(z) = $\frac{2}{3}$arg($z^2-z$)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I know that the first part of my question has been asked a year ago, but the solutions there don't help me, since I'm not familiar with the theorems they use there. 
So I'd be glad if someone had a basic approach to solve this.

The approach which lab bhattacharjee suggested is what I was looking for. I just need some help to develop it further, please.

Comment: Write $z=1+e^{it}=2e^{it/2}\cos\frac{t}{2}$ with $t\in\Bbb R$ so $z(z-1)=2e^{3it/2}\cos\frac{t}{2}$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for your help! I already did this and I know that a complex number x can be represented as $|x|e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta$ being arg(x). But I don't see why we are allowed to neglect that there is the term $2 cos(t/2)$. Maybe because of |z-1| = 1, I guess, but I don't know why?

Comment: A lot of this probably comes down to how you define arguments. If you restrict arguments to $(-\pi,\,\pi]$, $2\cos\frac{t}{2}$ can't be negative. (I'll leave you to look at what happens instead if we take $t\in[0,\,2\pi)$.) The case $z=1$ also technically doesn't work anyway, because what's the argument of $0$ supposed to be?

Comment: @J.G. If we took $t \in [0, 2\pi)$, then $2 cos \frac{t}{2}$ would be in $(-2,2]$. 
However, I don't see how this or considering the case $z=1$ is connected to my question?

Comment: @J.G. Also, why does $z = 2 cos t(cos t + i sin t)$ follow from $z-1 = cos2t + i sin 2t$?

Comment: Unfortunately my hint used $t$ to denote what @lab.bhattacharjee called $2t$, but either way what we're using is double-angle formulae. In that author's notation, $1+\cos 2t=2\cos^2t$ while $\sin 2t=2\sin t\cos t$.

Comment: @J.G. Okay, so then we have $z = cos(2t) + i sin(2t) +1 = 2cos^2(t) + i sin(2t) = 2 cos^2(t) + i (2 sin(t) cos(t)) = 2 cos(t) (cos(t) + i sin(t))$, which solves my last question. Thank you! But still, how do we get arg(z) from that? There's the disturbing factor $2 cos(t)$ in front of $e^{it}$?

Comment: It's only disturbing in terms of its sign. As long as it's positive, the argument is simply that of $\cos t+i\sin t$.

Comment: @J.G. Oh, okay... I already thought that this was the case, but do you have any explanation why's that? (Or a link to an explanation if it takes too long to explain that?) Because I really only know that $e^{it}$ is the representation of $x = cos(t) + i sin(t)$, I don't know anything else about how to handle factors or anything.

Comment: $t$ is the argument of $re^{it}$ when $r>0$, not just when $r=1$, so every nonzero complex number has a unique argument in $(-\pi,\,\pi]$.

Comment: @J.G. Okay, but the factor equals $|z|$? So here we have $|z| = 2 cos(t)$? 
And where did we use the precondition that $|z-1| = 1$? 
EDIT: Oh, we needed it to write $z-1$ as $e^{i2t}$, without any factor for |z-1| (since it equals 1), right?

Comment: When writing $z-1$ as $e^{it}$.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you, now everything is clear. You did help me enormously. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

WLOG arg$(z-1)=2t\implies z-1=\cos2t+i\sin2t$

$z=2\cos t(\cos t+i\sin t),$arg$(z)=?$

Now $z(z-1)=2\cos t(\cos t+i\sin t)(\cos2t+i\sin2t)=2\cos t(\cos3t+i\sin3t)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I don't know what arg(z) is then. Well, from an older post where a similar question was answered, I know that arg(z) = t is the solution, but I don't know why. 
And I also don't know what follows for arg(z(z-1)).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple consequence of the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle):

If $|z-1|=1$, the image $M$ of $z$ in the Argand-Cauchy plane is a point of the circle with center $I$ (the image of $1$) and its $\arg(z-1)$ is the polar angle of the straight line $(IM)$, i.e. a  central angle on this circle, and $\arg z$ is a corresponding inscribed angle.

Comment: Thanks for this information, but since I'm not familiar with this theorem, I'm looking for a more fundamental approach.

Comment: Wait, this theorem is taught in *middle-school*. I learnt it at the age of 14…

Comment: Well, good for you. Which country did you go to school? But on the one hand side, I really haven't, and on the other hand, as I said, I'm looking for a proof that doesn't use theorems of other mathematical fields than complex analysis itself.

Comment: But geometry can be recovered with complex numbers. No need for analysis for that. To answer your question: I'm from France.